# How to merge videos together use VLC command line（some video have one audio track, some video not have audio track）

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player

```
 vlc *.mp4 --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=all.mp4}" --no-sout-all --sout-keep
```

I have tried the above command, but it doesn't work.

Except for the number of audio tracks, these videos are inconsistent, some have no audio tracks, some have audio tracks, and other parameters are the same（frame rate, resolution...all same）

Answer (score 0):

Would need clarity on "it doesn't work" - what is the error or exit code? Try with a Verbose switch and include the output.

I think ffmpeg would be more suited to this than vlc. You can select which audio and video streams you want from each input.

To simply append one video to another you can:

```
cat video2.mp4 >> video1.mp4
```